# how to add outlook conditional css to wooocmmerce order email template customization?

Tags: php, css, woocommerce, outlook, html-email

I'm trying to customize, woocommerce order confirmation email. I'm trying to add padding "if it's mso  " to my logo_wrapper that contains a logo like this

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_styles', 'ga_woocommerce_email_styles' );
function ga_woocommerce_email_styles( $css ) {
    $css .="<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    <style>  #logo_wrapper{padding:10px !important;}</style>
    <![endif]-->";
    return $css;
}
```

it doesn't work as expected,if i try this $css .= " #logo_wrapper{padding:10px !important;}"; it works.But, I want the padding to work only for outlook client. I'm having trouble with the mso conditional.I also tried removing the  tag inside $css. Any suggestions on what's going wrong?

Comment: "It doesn't work as expected". Could you elaborate, please?

Does it come back with an error?
Does it apply the change but the condition isn't working?
Is the conditional style in the code after adding this?

Comment: @JGreatorex Thanks for the comment. If I remove the conditional style(("<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>")) in the code, it works(the padding is applied) but I want the padding only in case of an outlook email client.

Comment: Are you applying this to a table element or td (or other?).

It can be buggy on the table elements, if not might need to see the rest of your email. 

More about CSS compatibility in emails: 
[https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/padding/](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/padding/)

Comment: @JGreatorex Yes, i'm applying to a td .